# Dynamic nested dictionary access

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary in the format below:

```
input = {
    'f1': {
        'l1': { 'k1': 1.6, 't1': 1.4 },
        'l2': { 'k1': 1.5, 'k2': 1.8, 't1': 1.3 }
    }
}
```

The hierarchy of the dictionary is: feature->level->{key=key,value=number}

For every level in each feature, values of the keys `(k1, k2, k3, ...)` should be multiplied with the value of `'t1'` and the result should be added back to the dictionary under the key `"geo_" + key`.

Example:

In `l1` only one key (`k1`) is available, so the output `geo_k1 = k1 * t1`; whereas in `l2` there are two keys (`k1` & `k2`), so there will be two outputs: `geo_k1 = k1 * t1` & `geo_k2 = k2 * t1`.

Expected Output:

```
output = {
    'f1': {
        'l1': { 'k1': 1.6, 't1': 1.4, 'final_k1': 2.24 },
        'l2': { 'k1': 1.5, 'k2': 1.8, 't1': 1.3, 'final_k1': 1.95, 'final_k2': 2.34 }
    }
}
```

I tried with the following code, but not sure how to make it dynamic:

```
for k, v in input.items():
    for key, value in v.items():
        print(value[l1]['k1'] * value[l1]['t1'])
```

Comment: Why do you have separate `k1`, `k2`, etc. keys instead of putting them all in a list?

Comment: What do you mean by dynamic?

Comment: @OneCricketeer: Yes I am. Thought of doing it with dictionary manipulation; if it could not be done, will take that approach.

Comment: @MadPhysicist: There can be any number of keys inside every level

Comment: I would suggest a structure like `{t1: value, keys: [], geo_keys:[]}`

Comment: Your latest edit makes the question inconsistent. You talk about `geo_` in once place but expect `final_` in the output. I recommend rolling it back or at least fixing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's rename `input` to something that doesn't override a builtin:

```
data = {
    'f1': {
        'l1': { 'k1': 1.6, 't1': 1.4 },
        'l2': { 'k1': 1.5, 'k2': 1.8, 't1': 1.3 }
    }
}
```

Each dictionary has a number of methods that allow you to iterate over the keys, values, or both: `keys`, `values` and `items`, respectively. In fact dictionaries themselves are iterable over their keys. At the first nesting, you don't care about the feature names or level names:

```
for feature in data.values():
    for level in feature.values():
```

Next, let's grab the multiplier `t1` from each nested level:

```
        multiplier = level.get('t1', 1.0)
```

Now you are operating on each keyset, so you have to be careful to filter properly. If you try to modify `level` as you iterate, you will run into problems, so let's iterate over a copy of the key list, and modify in-place:

```
        for key in list(level.keys()):
            if key.startswith('k'):
                level['geo_' + key] = level[key] * multiplier
```

Another way to filter the keys is by using a comprehension in the loop. For example, if you allowed key names starting with other letters than `k`, and only wanted to omit `t1`:

```
        for key in [k for k in level if k != 't1']:
             level['geo_' + key] = level[key] * multiplier
```

The whole thing combined:

```
for feature in data.values():
    for level in feature.values():
        multiplier = level.get('t1', 1.0)
        for key in [k for k in level if k != 't1']:
             level['geo_' + key] = level[key] * multiplier
```

Comment: With slight modifiction, this worked. As there is no guarantee, all the keys start with 'k', I just added key_list = [ i for i in level.keys() if i!='total']; then iterated through the key_list

Comment: @user3447653. I've made an update to include your comment.

Answer (score 1):

In your inner loop, check whether the key starts with `k`. If so, perform the multiplication and create the corresponding `geo_kX` key.

```
for k1, v1 in input.items():
    for k2, v2 in v1.items():
        for k3, v3 in list(v2.items()):
            if k3.startswith('k'):
                v2['geo_' + k3] = v2['t1'] * v3
```

It's necessary to use `list(v2.items())` to avoid the error:

> RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration